# Merging duplicate nodes in an to form a new XML using XSLT

Tags: xslt

i have an XML as below. Where differenct items come for delete or add. each item will have serial number. what i trying to do is  i want to prepare a new xml from these input in such a way that, if an item with an item code has come for add and delete i want to merge them into a single item node. The new item formed will have action code as update and sino will be add item sino and oldsino will be delete item sino.

## INPUT

`

---

```
<ITEM> 
    <SINO>1</SINO>
    <ITEMCODE>101</ITEMNAME> 
    <ACTION>ADD</ACTION>
    <OLDSINO></OLDSINO>
</ITEM>
<ITEM> 
    <SINO>2</SINO>
    <ITEMCODE>101</ITEMNAME> 
    <ACTION>DELETE</ACTION>
    <OLDSINO></OLDSINO>
</ITEM>
<ITEM> 
    <SINO>3</SINO>
    <ITEMCODE>102</ITEMNAME> 
    <ACTION>ADD</ACTION>
    <OLDSINO></OLDSINO>
</ITEM>
<ITEM> 
    <SINO>4</SINO>
    <ITEMCODE>103</ITEMNAME> 
    <ACTION>ADD</ACTION>
    <OLDSINO></OLDSINO>
</ITEM>
<ITEM> 
    <SINO>5</SINO>
    <ITEMCODE>103</ITEMNAME> 
    <ACTION>DELETE</ACTION>
    <OLDSINO></OLDSINO>
</ITEM>
<ITEM> 
    <SINO>6</SINO>
    <ITEMCODE>104</ITEMNAME> 
    <ACTION>DELETE</ACTION>
    <OLDSINO></OLDSINO>
</ITEM>
```

`

## OUTPUT

`

---

```
<ITEM> 
    <SINO>1</SINO>
    <ITEMCODE>101</ITEMNAME> 
    <ACTION>UPDATE</ACTION>
    <OLDSINO>2</OLDSINO>
</ITEM>
<ITEM> 
    <SINO>3</SINO>
    <ITEMCODE>102</ITEMNAME> 
    <ACTION>ADD</ACTION>
    <OLDSINO></OLDSINO>
</ITEM>
<ITEM> 
    <SINO>4</SINO>
    <ITEMCODE>103</ITEMNAME> 
    <ACTION>DELETE</ACTION>
    <OLDSINO>5</OLDSINO>
</ITEM>
<ITEM> 
    <SINO>6</SINO>
    <ITEMCODE>104</ITEMNAME> 
    <ACTION>DELETE</ACTION>
    <OLDSINO></OLDSINO>
</ITEM>
```

`

Any ideas how to acheive this using XSLT.

Comment: +1 good question (even if the output sample is not correct on the basis of your description).

Comment: I mean the third ITEM/ACTION element should be UPDATE.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and efficient solution based on the most fundamental XSLT desigh patterns -- the overriding of the identity rule/template.

Comment: Just to check, an add followed by a delete is an update using the sino of the later delete or should add then delete just be merged into nothing and a delete then add merge into an update?

Answer (score 1):

> *if an item with an item code has come for add and delete i want to merge them into a single item node. The new item formed will have action code as update and sino will be add item sino and oldsino will be delete item sino*

This solution mainly plays with template match patterns on siblings, and exploits the identity rule.

XSLT 1.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ITEM[
            ITEMCODE[../ACTION='ADD']
        =
                ../ITEM/ITEMCODE[../ACTION='DELETE']]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <SINO><xsl:value-of select="../ITEM[ITEMCODE
                    =current()/ITEMCODE and ACTION='ADD']/
                    SINO"/>
            </SINO>
            <xsl:copy-of select="ITEMCODE"/>
            <ACTION>UPDATE</ACTION>
            <OLDSINO><xsl:value-of select="../ITEM[ITEMCODE
                    =current()/ITEMCODE and ACTION='DELETE']/
                    SINO"/>
            </OLDSINO>          
        </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:template>

            <xsl:template match="ITEM[
            ITEMCODE[../ACTION='DELETE']
        =
                ../ITEM/ITEMCODE[../ACTION='ADD']]"/>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The solution produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<ITEMS>
    <ITEM>
        <SINO>1</SINO>
        <ITEMCODE>101</ITEMCODE>
        <ACTION>UPDATE</ACTION>
        <OLDSINO>2</OLDSINO>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <SINO>3</SINO>
        <ITEMCODE>102</ITEMCODE>
        <ACTION>ADD</ACTION>
        <OLDSINO></OLDSINO>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <SINO>4</SINO>
        <ITEMCODE>103</ITEMCODE>
        <ACTION>UPDATE</ACTION>
        <OLDSINO>5</OLDSINO>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <SINO>6</SINO>
        <ITEMCODE>104</ITEMCODE>
        <ACTION>DELETE</ACTION>
        <OLDSINO></OLDSINO>
    </ITEM>
</ITEMS>
```

Comment: What will this solution produce if there are more than one "ADD" or "DELETE" actions on the same `ITEMCODE` and there are no actions of *both* "ADD" and "DELETE" for the same `ITEMCODE`? I think this code makes too-many assumptions about the XML document -- that may or maynot be true.

Comment: @Dimitre-Novatchev: I'll check better; even if the assumptions are based on the rough OP description, you are probably true. It works fine anyway if applied on the OP input sample.

Comment: @Dimitre-Novatchev: I've changed the transform a bit to make it more general. Does not manage multiple ADD for the same ITEMCODE, but there is no mention of the OP to manage this situation.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a short and simple solutions that overrides the identity rule/template:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kItemByCode" match="ITEM"
  use="ITEMCODE"/>

 <xsl:key name="kActionByCode" match="ACTION"
  use="../ITEMCODE"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "ITEM[not(generate-id() =
            generate-id(key('kItemByCode', ITEMCODE)[1])
            )
        ]"/>

 <xsl:template match=
   "ITEM[generate-id() =
         generate-id(key('kItemByCode', ITEMCODE)[1])
        and
         key('kActionByCode', ITEMCODE) = 'ADD'
        and
         key('kActionByCode', ITEMCODE) = 'DELETE'
        ]
        /ACTION/text()
   ">
        <xsl:text>UPDATE</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
   "ITEM[generate-id() =
         generate-id(key('kItemByCode', ITEMCODE)[1])
        and
         key('kActionByCode', ITEMCODE) = 'ADD'
        and
         key('kActionByCode', ITEMCODE) = 'DELETE'
        ]
        /OLDSINO
   ">
    <OLDSINO>
     <xsl:apply-templates mode="List"
      select="key('kItemByCode', ../ITEMCODE)[position()>1]" />
    </OLDSINO>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ITEM" mode="List">
  <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">,</xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="SINO"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (based on and correcting the provided severely malformed XML fragment):

```
<t>
    <ITEM>
        <SINO>1</SINO>
        <ITEMCODE>101</ITEMCODE>
        <ACTION>ADD</ACTION>
        <OLDSINO></OLDSINO>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <SINO>2</SINO>
        <ITEMCODE>101</ITEMCODE>
        <ACTION>DELETE</ACTION>
        <OLDSINO></OLDSINO>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <SINO>3</SINO>
        <ITEMCODE>102</ITEMCODE>
        <ACTION>ADD</ACTION>
        <OLDSINO></OLDSINO>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <SINO>4</SINO>
        <ITEMCODE>103</ITEMCODE>
        <ACTION>ADD</ACTION>
        <OLDSINO></OLDSINO>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <SINO>5</SINO>
        <ITEMCODE>103</ITEMCODE>
        <ACTION>DELETE</ACTION>
        <OLDSINO></OLDSINO>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <SINO>6</SINO>
        <ITEMCODE>104</ITEMCODE>
        <ACTION>DELETE</ACTION>
        <OLDSINO></OLDSINO>
    </ITEM>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<t>
  <ITEM>
    <SINO>1</SINO>
    <ITEMCODE>101</ITEMCODE>
    <ACTION>UPDATE</ACTION>
    <OLDSINO>2</OLDSINO>
  </ITEM>
  <ITEM>
    <SINO>3</SINO>
    <ITEMCODE>102</ITEMCODE>
    <ACTION>ADD</ACTION>
    <OLDSINO />
  </ITEM>
  <ITEM>
    <SINO>4</SINO>
    <ITEMCODE>103</ITEMCODE>
    <ACTION>UPDATE</ACTION>
    <OLDSINO>5</OLDSINO>
  </ITEM>
  <ITEM>
    <SINO>6</SINO>
    <ITEMCODE>104</ITEMCODE>
    <ACTION>DELETE</ACTION>
    <OLDSINO />
  </ITEM>
</t>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The identity rule/template copies every node "as-is".
2. A template with empty body overrides the identity rule for every non-first `ITEM` of a group of `ITEM` elements with the same `ITEMCODE` -- any such node isn't copied to the output (aka deleted).
3. A third template overrides the identity rule for every `ITEM` element that is the first in a group of `ITEM` elements with the same `ITEMCODE` and for whose `ITEMCODE` there are items with `ACTION` both "ADD" and "DELETE". It constructs the necessary `OLDSINO` element by applying templates in mode "List" to all `ITEM` elements in the group, but the first one.
4. The Muenchian method for grouping and generally keys are used so that an efficient and compact implementation is achieved.
5. This solution works correctly with any arbitrary mixture of `ITEM` elements that may have the same `ITEMCODE`.

Comment: This solution does not totally fulfills the OP requirement of having OLDSINO element correctly populated.

Comment: @empo: your comment was made on the old answer and is no longer true -- do have a look at the updated solution.

Comment: I'm still seeing empty OLDSINO elements in the output of this post.

Comment: Moreover, if the ITEM 'ADD' comes after the one 'DELETE' the SINO element is wrongly set to the 'DELETE' serial.

Comment: @empo: OK, I hadn't even seen the requirement for OLDSINO -- will update at the first possible moment. :)

Comment: @empo: I think that the code now does correctly everything asked by the OP. Do you still see any problems? :)

Comment: I see, we had just a rough description and a wrong output sample :). Anyway, my third comment above is still true.

Comment: @empo: What exactly is not OK? I don't know what you mean by "my third comment above". The produced output is identical to the one the OP wants. Should there be any alleged issu, please describee it directly. Show the output item(s) that you think are incorrect and explain what/why is incorrect.

Comment: Try to place an "Add" ITEM with same code _after_ the one with "Delete". The output ITEM will have SINO equal to "Delete" and not "Add" which seems not what the OP requested.

Comment: However, I think is not worth this question, due mainly to the lack of consideration (and details) given by the OP. Do you agree :)?

Comment: @empo: Your example seems to be incorrect. If I have Delete and Add for 101 (in this order) the output wanted by the OP is UPDATE and this is exactly what my code produces. Seems you have been mistaken all this time saying there is a problem with this solution. Do you really have a correct example of an issue with this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Correcting for the typo (opening ITEMCODE tag and closing ITEMNAME tag) and working with a root element of ITEMS a complete XSLT could be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="deletes" match="ITEM[ACTION='DELETE']" use="ITEMCODE/text()"/>
  <xsl:key name="adds" match="ITEM[ACTION='ADD']" use="ITEMCODE/text()"/>

  <xsl:template match="ITEMS">
    <ITEMS>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ITEM" />
    </ITEMS>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="ITEM[ACTION='ADD' and key('deletes',ITEMCODE/text())]">
        <xsl:variable name="current" select="ITEMCODE/text()"/>
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="name()='ACTION'">
                <ACTION>UPDATE</ACTION>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test="name()='OLDSINO'">
                <OLDSINO><xsl:value-of select="key('deletes',$current)/SINO/text()"/></OLDSINO>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ITEM[ACTION='ADD' and not(key('deletes',ITEMCODE/text()))]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
   </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ITEM[ACTION='DELETE' and not(key('adds',ITEMCODE/text()))]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ITEM" />

  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The produced output of this transform holds an empty `OLDSINO` element. Please correct.